# Pixmap not drawn on promoted label subclass

Tags: qt, subclass, qt-designer, qlabel, paintevent

I'm subClassing `QLabel` and painting a `QPixmap` via `QPainter`, it works fine, the problem is I can't change the image path of the pixmap and re-call the `paintEvent` function so it repaints the pixmap with the new Image.

I added a label from Qt Designer (i.e drag and drop) then promoted it to this subclass.

**useravatar.h**:

```
#ifndef USERAVATAR_H
#define USERAVATAR_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QObject>
#include <QPen>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>

class userAvatar : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QString photoLocation;
    userAvatar(QWidget *parent);
    void setPath(const QString &path);
private:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;
};

#endif // USERAVATAR_H
```

**useravatar.cpp**:

```
#include "useravatar.h"
#include <unistd.h>

userAvatar::userAvatar(QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent)
{
}

void userAvatar::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    QPainter painter(this);

    QPixmap pixmap(photoLocation);
    qDebug() << photoLocation; // outputs EMPTY string
    QPixmap scaled = pixmap.scaled(width(), height(), Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

    QBrush bruch(scaled);
    bruch.setColor(Qt::black);
    painter.setBrush(bruch);

    painter.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, width(), height(), 100, 100);
}

void userAvatar::setPath(const QString &path)
{
    photoLocation = path;
    update();
}
```

**widget.cpp**:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include "useravatar.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    
    userAvatar *avatar = new userAvatar(nullptr);
    avatar->setPath("E:/NetWork__Installs/kitty meme.jpg");
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I get this error from `painEvent`:

> QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
userAvatar *avatar = new userAvatar(nullptr);
avatar->setPath("E:/NetWork__Installs/kitty meme.jpg");
```

This does not get added to the ui, it won't be visible, its `paintEvent` won't be called, meaning the error you get is not from this object.

The `userAvatar` that does emit that error is instantiated in `ui_widget.h` and visible.

To set `photoLocation` of the `userAvatar` in your ui, use this:

```
ui->yourUserAvatar->setPath("/path/to/image.png");
```

`yourUserAvatar` is whatever you named your `userAvatar` in Qt Designer.